# MySql data datatype with Java

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert a date in my DB(phpmyadmin server) that has the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`  . Here is the code that does this :

```
// get form parameters
        String pDate = request.getParameter("poll_date");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        try {
            polDate = dateFormat.parse(pDate);
            pollDate = new java.sql.Date(polDate.getTime());
        } catch(ParseException pe)
        {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the insertion in DB code

```
String sql = "INSERT into polls (POLL_DATE, POLL_TYPES, POLL_STATUS) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            ps = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setDate(1, pollDate);
            ps.setString(2, pollType);
            ps.setInt(3, 1);
            numInserted = ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And it returns me a message That the Dateformat is not ok.

What is it to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the MySql function `DATE_FORMAT()`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

I hope I could help.